# Hitting java.lang.IllegalStateException: null when call setAttribute() in HttpSession

Tags: java, websphere, illegalstateexception, httpsession

Good day,

The following is my java code:

```
Map< String, Account > accountMap = result.getAccountsMap( );
if ( accountMap != null )
    command.getSession( ).setAttribute( Constants.OA, accountMap );
```

And then on and off it will hitting `IllegalStateException` since today morning:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: null
>   at com.ibm.ws.session.http.HttpSessionImpl.setAttribute(HttpSessionImpl.java:248)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>         at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionData.putSessionValue(SessionData.java:293)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>         at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionData.setAttribute(SessionData.java:217)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>         at com.ibm.ws.session.HttpSessionFacade.setAttribute(HttpSessionFacade.java:169)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]

I tried to google about this, but its seems like a very common exception, and I have no idea how/where should I continue to troubleshoot.

This application is running on WAS 8.5.5.

Can anyone advise me on this?

Comment: If you have the uncompiled source, I would suggest going into the `setAttribute` method and seeing the condition where that `Exception` is thrown; that often gives a good hint as to why you're getting your error.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the session is invalid at this point. Can you add a check to `isRequestedSessionIdValid()`? The fact that you're pulling it from a `command` object, rather than from an `HttpServletRequest` directly, means it could easily be an old, invalidated one.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, this was due to the method is called on an invalidated session:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)

HttpServletRequest.getSession(false) should also returns null at that point.